# python constructor basic question

Tags: python, constructor

I am trying to reuse an opened file which is declared inside the constructor instance of a class but I guess I am doing something logically wrong. For instance consider the following example

```
class Temp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.open_file_ = open('periodic_status','r')

    def function1(self):
        new_file = self.open_file_
        for i in new_file:
            print 'test1'

    def function2(self):
        for j in self.open_file_:
            print 'test2'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1 = Temp()
    obj1.function1()
    obj1.function2()
```

In the above program I can print test1 but I am not able to print the statement test2. Can some one explain me the logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your file handle has exhausted all the lines in the file. You need to rewind it in "function2" using:

```
f.seek(0)
```

to start over again

See here [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: Ok, but how to check whether I exhausted all the lines in the file?

Answer (score 2):

Copying the reference does not create a new iterator; the first round of iteration consumes the entire file, leaving none for the second. You'll need to seek back to the beginning if you want to read it again.

Comment: true, can you explain me how to seek back to the beginning of file.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `open_file_.seek(0)` in the beginning of function to reset the file position to the beginning (its at the end of the file after reading it all in function1()).